# PayPal ignores the billing_country field, defaults to "United States"

Tags: paypal

Recently I was testing a site I maintain, based in Canada.

I found that when arriving at the PayPal payment, the country field was set to `United States`, despite the fact that I have set `billing_country` set to `CA`.

How can I get PayPal to respect the `billing_country` I have set?

I have reproduced the same behaviour on the paypal sandbox.

Here is the relevant PayPal form with all variables:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">                                                              
<input name="item_name_1" value="Test Item" type="hidden">                                                                                                      
<input name="business" value="test-business@example.com" type="hidden">                                                                                   
<input name="email" value="test-customer@example.com" type="hidden">                                                                                                  
<input name="cmd" value="_cart" type="hidden">                                                                                                                  
<input name="charset" value="utf-8" type="hidden">                                                                                                              
<input name="upload" value="1" type="hidden">                                                                                                                   
<input name="amount_1" value="10.00" type="hidden">                                                                                                             
<input name="quantity_1" value="1" type="hidden">                                                                                                               
<input name="tax_cart" value="0.00" type="hidden">                                                                                                              
<input name="currency_code" value="CAD" type="hidden">                                                                                                          
<input name="lc" value="CA" type="hidden">                                                                                                                      
<input name="no_shipping" value="1" type="hidden">                                                                                                              
<input name="no_note" value="1" type="hidden">                                                                                                                  
<input name="address_override" value="1" type="hidden">                                                                                                         
<input name="country" value="CA" type="hidden">                                                                                                                 
<input name="address1" value="123 Broadway" type="hidden">                                                                                                      
<input name="city" value="Winnipeg" type="hidden">                                                                                                              
<input name="state" value="MB" type="hidden">                                                                                                                   
<input name="zip" value="R3G 1N1" type="hidden">                                                                                                                
<input name="night_phone_a" value="555" type="hidden">                                                                                                          
<input name="night_phone_b" value="555" type="hidden">                                                                                                          
<input name="night_phone_c" value="5555" type="hidden">                                                                                                         
<input style="vertical-align: middle" name="continue" value="Continue" type="submit">                                                                           
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through testing and comparing code against a different site where this issue does not occur, I have determined this is a PayPal bug.

The workaround I found is to set:

```
<input name="landing_page" value="billing" type="hidden">
```

After setting this variable, PayPal started to respect the `billing_country` field I set.